# Unable to resolve "art/core/class.js" from "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART/ARTSerializablePath.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, watchman

While running "expo start" in the terminal, I randomly got this error:

> (node:96689) UnhandledPromisRejectWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
> [image: Error 1]

I've been building and downloading the javascript bundle over the last several weeks with no problems. After building the project, I got the error even though I did not do anything differently in code. Just before, it was building with no problem.

After attempting to do the following command in terminal (npm install debug --save), I got the following error:

Unable to resolve "art/core/class.js" from "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART/ARTSericalizablePath.js"
[image: Error 2]

Now, on the iOS simulator, I get a different error and suggestion for resolving it.

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`
2. Delete the 'node_modules' folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- -- reset-cache`
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`

[image: Error 3]

However, to my understanding, if I delete the node modules folder, wouldn't that also delete the modules for the dependencies that I'm using?

If that's the case, how would I go about getting those dependency modules back?

Answer (score 0):

The `node_modules` directory will be recreated next time you run `npm install`, and all dependencies will be re installed. You can delete it safely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I try to do the first command: "watchman watch-del-all" I get command not found. I assume that watchman is not installed? I thought that it was created when I started the react native project. Do you suggest just running npm install?

Comment: Yes, it can't hurt

Answer (score 0):

First, deleting the node_modules won't harm. Just run `npm install`

**Regarding the error**

Do as instructed by the app.

if you failed, try restarting the npm server by:

`react-native start --reset-cache`

in case that failed ensure that there are no processes listening to the port that node server will use to do so
`kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:PORT_USED_BY_NODE)`